# What does zero entries mean in GHC profile report?

Tags: haskell, profiling, ghc

If I understand correctly the [documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html) `entries` refers to how many times the expression that the cost center corresponds to was evaluated. But in the prof reports (even the examples in the documentation page) many cost centers have zero `entries` but non-zero `%time`. What am I missing?